# Android Studio - How to "create" an Android project from a Github repo that only contains Readme & License

Tags: android, git, github

I'm doing a project for school.

There is an existing repository on Github that me and my team will use. It's an any-platform project so the repo only contains a LICENSE file and a README.md file. I'm going to be doing an Android project, so in Android Studio I did new->project from version control->Github. It imports the license/readme files fine, but it's not an Android project...no Android structure and gradle files.

**How can I, now in the newly created project, get the basic Android files/structure generated?**

Previously I tried to just create a new Android project from scratch and the structure and files were all there but it would only allow me to push to a branch, not master. It was saying it was rejected because it had totally different histories or something

Comment: copypasta the android project you set up into the Github project folder

Comment: Says there's too many files. I'm trying to do it folder by folder and file by file but it's messing up the structure. ugh

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simply adding a remote in the root directory and then making sure the local project is up to date with the remote repo.